# Calculating days since last game from season schedule

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with the entire NBA season schedule (see image).

[image: data format of schedule]

i would like to be able to search columns b and c in "NBA Schedule" using cell A1 of "NBA Data" find the date of the last game then calculate days since?

thanks

more detailed info

in sheet "NBA Data" i have column A1 which has the team value, in column B1 i would like to have the amount of days since they last played. this data can be found in the sheet "NBA Schedule".

i need to search columns B and C in "NBA Schedule", find the last game the team from A1 in "NBA Data" then save the amount of days since the last game in B1 in "NBA Data"

Comment: Do you want a cell with a dropdown allowing you to select a team and then output how long since the team's last game?

Comment: right now i have now a dropdown with all the team names in cell A1 in "NBA Data" but yes thats exactly what im trying to work out.. how to get days since last game in cell B1 in "NBA Data"

Comment: if *Lakers* has these game dates for eg: *Jan 25*, *Jan 28*, *Feb 5 2024*, so whats the expected output for this scenario here?!

Comment: thanks thats a great question.. the expected output would be  3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you sample spreadsheet, this is the formula:

```
=ifna(today() - max(filter('NBA Schedule '!A2:A,'NBA Schedule '!A2:A<TODAY(), ('NBA Schedule '!B2:B=A2) + ('NBA Schedule '!C2:C=A2))), "Nothing found")
```

It filters only the games with a date before today.  Important: you need to format the cells in `'NBA Schedule '!A2:A` range as dates.

---

More generic formulas:

1. You can use this formula:

   ```
   =ifna(today() - max(filter(A2:A, B2:B=A1, C2:C=B1)), "Nothing found")
   ```

   1. `A2:A` - column with dates.
   2. `B2:B` - column with the first team.
   3. `C2:C` - column with the second team.
   4. `A1` - cell with the name of the first team.
   5. `B1` - cell with the name of the second team.

   You will need to adjust cells' coordinates to fit your sheet setup.
2. If in some games teams can be in different positions, this is the formula that ignores the position of the team:

   ```
   =ifna(today() - max(filter(A2:A, (B2:B=A1) + (B2:B=B1), (C2:C=A1) + (C2:C=B1))), "Nothing found")
   ```
3. If you need to find the latest game of a team regardless with whom they played:

   ```
   =ifna(today() - max(filter(A2:A, (B2:B=A1) + (C2:C=A1))), "Nothing found")
   ```

Comment: i added additional more detailed info and would only need to account for the single team no matter who they played

Comment: @ShadyTree Could you share a sample sheet, please.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kJRg_CY-UFPym7IWy1_sjTHAjNIZAIAkiR1KelGWLLo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @dataful.tech and @ShadyTree, this seems to work `=ifna(today() - max(filter('NBA Schedule '!A2:A,'NBA Schedule '!A2:A<TODAY(), ('NBA Schedule '!B2:B=A2) + ('NBA Schedule '!C2:C=A2))), "Nothing found")`.  Building off of your formula #3, this adds the condition that the dates to evaluate must be before today.  Also, the dates in "NBA Schedule" sheet need to be formatted as dates.

Comment: yup works great thanks both of you... i appreciate the time spent helping me.. the only change i made was  added -1 to today() "today()-1"